# Cannot log in to a Cisco 891W via terminal, ssh

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, cisco-isr

I have already referred to this similar question: [Telnet or SSH into a Cisco router](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44721/telnet-or-ssh-into-a-cisco-router) but the procedure did not work for me.

I have a Cisco 891W. I am able to log in via the console port just fine with username:password. I see a Telnet interface and get an interactive prompt there, but using the same username:password that is successful on console login fails. Likewise, attempting to access a web interface at the same IP with the same credentials fails.

Here is a portion of my `show run` to give an idea of what's been done.

```
enable secret 5 mysecret
enable password mypassword
!
aaa new-model
!
aaa authentication login default local
!
username myuser password 0 mypassword
username admin privilege 15 secret 5 mysecret
!
ip access-list standard access-internal-only
 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
!
control-plane host
 management-interface FastEthernet0 allow https ssh snmp
line vty 0 4
 access-class access-internal-only in
 password mypassword
 transport input telnet ssh
line vty 5 15
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have

```
line vty 0 4
  password mypassword
```

you need to connect with "mypassword".

If you want to connect with the user "mysuser" you need to enter the command

```
line vty 0 15
   login local
```

Note that telnet is highly insecure, you should disable it and use only ssh, with `transport input ssh`

Also you shouldn't use

```
username myuser password 0 mypassword
```

but rather

```
username myuser secret 0 mypassword
```

with

```
service password encryption
```

so your password are encrypted in a secure way. The "password" encryption method is kept for compatibility purpose but it is not secure at all (you can find on line tool to decrypt such passwords).

Comment: With `aaa new-model`, the old line password doesn't apply. (hint: it asks for a username) His control-plane policy doesn't allow telnet.

Comment: `login local` was invalid after `line vty 0 15`. A suggested alternative from the CLI was `login authentication default`. I do have the line `aaa authentication login default local` in my `show run`. Is `login authentication default` supposed to be a valid alternative? I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like most of my problem is not understanding `aaa`. Not sure why it was enabled, so now I've disabled it. I was able to put in `login local` but that didn't solve my ability to authenticate over telnet. (I realize `ssh` is the better solution, I'm just trying to solve the auth issue then move to hardening)